# Update data all datetimeoffset columns of all tables of the database to be incremented by 1 day using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

Update data all `datetimeoffset` columns of all tables of the database to be incremented by 1 day using SQL Server.

**Note**: I want to update all the columns in all the tables in the database which are of type `datetimeoffset` and have value.

I want to update them by incrementing 1 day.

I am trying to find the solution but am not able to any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or PL/SQL (which is for Oracle)?

Comment: You tagged both SQL-Server and PLSQL which to the best of my knowledge can't really be used together. Now, I may be wrong but do check your tags.

Comment: sql server iam using

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL for this, and there are some caveats.

```
DECLARE @cmd  nvarchar(max),
        @base nvarchar(max) = N'UPDATE &T& ' 
              + N' SET &C& = DATEADD(DAY, 1, &C&)';

SELECT @cmd = STRING_AGG(REPLACE(REPLACE(@base, 
       N'&T&', QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)),
       N'&C&', QUOTENAME(c.name)), ';' + char(13) + char(10))
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
  JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON t.object_id = c.object_id
  WHERE c.system_type_id = 43
    AND c.is_computed = 0;

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @cmd;
```

This will produce a command like:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[t1]  SET [dt] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [dt]);
UPDATE [dbo].[t2]  SET [col5] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [col5]);
...
```

Now, the caveats:

1. Many solutions you'll find out there will just look for types *named* `datetimeoffset`. This solution also covers alias types (e.g. `CREATE TYPE dbo.blat FROM datetimeoffset;`).
2. Many solutions will not check if a column is computed, which means you can't update it directly. This solution ignores those columns.
3. If it's possible in your system for a schema name or table name to contain the string `&C&`, use a different token format, or emoji characters, or basically any string that won't naturally occur in an entity name (I can't tell you any string that *can't* occur in an entity name but *can* occur in a string that is valid and executable, because that is the empty set).

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GYNKDXo8).